# How to remove the whitespace between my two horizontal list views?

Tags: flutter

Currently running into an issue where I have two containers which are horizontal listviews, within the containers i'm building out these cards which are the "recipes"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:newapp/views/widgets/cookBookWidgets/shoe_page.dart';
import '../widgets/cookBookWidgets/cookBook_appbar.dart';
import '../widgets/cookBookWidgets/cookBook_searchBar.dart';

class CookbookPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CookbookPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CookbookPage> createState() => _CookbookPageState();
}

class CardItem {
  final String urlImage;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;

  const CardItem({
    required this.urlImage,
    required this.title,
    required this.subtitle,
  });
}

class _CookbookPageState extends State<CookbookPage> {
  List<CardItem> recipeItems = [
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Chicken Alfredo',
      subtitle: 'Servings',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Cajun Chicken Alfredo',
      subtitle: 'Servings',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Chipotle Chicken Tacos',
      subtitle: 'Servings',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Classic Italian Tiramisu ',
      subtitle: 'Servings',
    ),
  ];

  List<CardItem> secondItems = [
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Second Item',
      subtitle: 'Subtitle for Second Item',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Second Item',
      subtitle: 'Subtitle for Second Item',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Second Item',
      subtitle: 'Subtitle for Second Item',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Second Item',
      subtitle: 'Subtitle for Second Item',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.p-tq9C_7CHoV2EKOQx4OmAHaHa?w=218&h=218&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=2&pid=1.7',
      title: 'Second Item',
      subtitle: 'Subtitle for Second Item',
    ),
    // add more CardItems as needed
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: cookBookAppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SearchBar(),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          buildSectionTitle(title: 'Your Recipes'),
          Expanded(
            child: buildContainer(recipeItems: recipeItems),
          ),
          buildSectionTitle(title: 'Recently Created'),
          Expanded(
            child: buildContainer(recipeItems: secondItems),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildSectionTitle({required String title}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Add your button logic here
            },
            child: Text(
              'See All',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
            ),
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              side: BorderSide.none,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
            ).copyWith(
              splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildContainer({required List<CardItem> recipeItems}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0, 16.0, 0.0),
      child: ListView.separated(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: recipeItems.length,
        separatorBuilder: (context, _) => SizedBox(width: 10),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildCard(item: recipeItems[index]),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildCard({
    required CardItem item,
  }) =>
      SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Material(
                  child: Ink.image(
                    image: NetworkImage(item.urlImage),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ShoePage(
                                  urlImage: item.urlImage, title: item.title)),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            Container(
              child: Text(
                item.title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            // Text(
            //   item.subtitle,
            //   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            // )
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

[image: Issue]

I wrapped the Sizedbox in a container and set it to black to see where the issue is.

[image]

I'm not sure whats going on within the SizedBox because there's no padding being added to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped your widgets in Expanded. So they expand :)

When you put an Expanded widget in a Column, you tell it to take all the available space.

EDIT:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SearchBar(),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        buildSectionTitle(title: 'Your Recipes'),
        buildContainer(recipeItems: recipeItems),
        buildSectionTitle(title: 'Recently Created'),
        buildContainer(recipeItems: secondItems),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: When wrapping the listview in a container I was able to set constraints on the height so that worked

Comment: Sounds like an unnecessary hack. :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: There is no reason to have Expanded in your widget tree. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

you should use expanded() as last widget in your columns

Columns(
children:[
Expanded(
child: buildContainer(recipeItems: recipeItems),
),
buildSectionTitle(title: 'Recently Created'),
Expanded(
child: buildContainer(recipeItems: secondItems),
),
Expanded(child: Container())

])

Comment: This will simply split the column into 3 areas by adding an empty Container.

Comment: So maybe your question isn't clear, beceause this is the only worked solution for your asked question

Comment: @AndreiVolgin be polite,
you are totally wrong and your answer also wrong, try your code it won't work, listview should be wrapped by expanded widget, according to he's use case, so the only useful answer is to use third expanded widget to fill the space

Answer (score -2):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: cookBookAppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SearchBar(),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          buildSectionTitle(title: 'Your Recipes'),
          Expanded(
            child: buildContainer(recipeItems: recipeItems),
          ),
          buildSectionTitle(title: 'Recently Created'),
          Container(
            height: 340,
            child: buildContainer(recipeItems: secondItems),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

needed to wrap my listview into a container so I could set constraints on the height, beware that the text could overflow if not dealt with properly.
[image]